# How can I embed NavigationController to Viewcontroller in xib

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, hierarchy

I have a viewcontroller lets say `A` that created with `xib` and I want to add navigationController to it .

View hierarchy :

```
UITabbarController -> NavigationController -> B Viewcontroller (A added tabbarcontroller in here when a button in B click)
```

I add `A` view to Tabbar in `B` Viewcontroller's button action like

```
tabBarController?.view.addSubview(A.view)
```

With this result , View `A` appears on Tabbar that what I want.

In A viewController there is a `Tableview` has some datas.When I click a row I want to push another Viewcontroller with `self.navigationController.push(..)` But I can't push anything because `UITabbarController` doesnt have a navigationController so I want to add `NavigationController` to `A viewController` . I searched lots of things but can't find any possible solution for it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController` and add it to the view hierarchy.

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aViewController)
```

Also, to append a new view controller to the `UITabBarController`'s `viewControllers` use:

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.append(navigationController)
```

Or:

```
tabBarController?.viewControllers?.insert(navigationController, at: 0)
```

Comment: insert or append adding new tabbar item to tabbarcontroller so I use `addChild` to tabbar.The issue how can I remove this navigation when A view closed? I want to everytime when Button in B clicked @frankenstein

Answer (score 0):

Based on your view hierarchy

```
UITabbarController -> NavigationController -> B Viewcontroller
```

You must append ViewController not ViewController's view

```
    func addMoreViewController() {
        let aViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aViewController)
        
        self.viewControllers.append(aViewController)
    }
```